# Second-Order Stochastic Dominance and Cost Minimization

Tags: probability, integration, optimization

I have to deal with a cost minimization problem with a cost function $c(t)$ at least twice differentiable, where $c'(t)>0$ and $c''(t)<0$. I have two density functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$.

If I were maximizing an utility function rather minimizing a cost function , then I could use second-order stochastic dominance to say that:

$u(t) f(t) > u(t) g(t)$ if $\int_{-\infty}^x G(t)-F(t) \, \mathrm{d}t >0 $ and $E_F(t) \geq E_G(t)$.

When dealing with cost minimization, can I say the converse, i.e., that risk-averse cost minimizers will prefer $f(t)$ to $g(t)$ such that:

$c(t) f(t) < c(t) g(t) $ if $\int_{-\infty}^x G(t)-F(t) \, \mathrm{d}t >0 $ and $E_F(t) \leq E_G(t)$,

where of course this captures the fact that less risk is still a good thing, but we prefer smaller draws from the distribution function?